# Different PATH formats for .bash_profile

Tags: bash, path

There are few different formats I have seen so far:

1. With quotes and brackets:

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
   ```
2. With quotes only:

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
   ```
3. None:

   ```
   PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
   ```

Export all the same:

```
export PATH
```

Which is the correct/preferred way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about shell variables in general, not just PATH.

Here are some examples of why `""` and `{}` can reduce errors.

Putting it in quotes is safer: if you do `a=hello world` then you will not get what you expect, but for `a="hello world"` you will.

Using `{}` is also safer: doing `h="hello"; echo "$hword"` will not work, but `h="hello"; echo "${h}word"` will.

Answer (score 1):

They all are effective. One isn't drastically better than the other, but I prefer:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

It takes care of the export and the setting of the path in one line. I also tend to not put the new path before the existing `$PATH`, but there are cases when that might be necessary to load newer self-compiled libraries before older system ones.

---

If you are trying to export variables then yes, you want to quote them, for instance:

```
export myservers="server1 server2 server3"
```

Now when you `echo $myservers` you will see:

```
[user]# echo $myservers
server1 server2 server3
```

But since this question relates to `$PATH` and not shell variables, then my original post still stands since there will never be a time where you are printing `'hello world'` into your system path.

```
[user]# echo $PATH  ## Something you shouldn't be doing
/usr/local/bin:HELLO WORLD/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:WHY AM I DOING THIS?/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

Comment: Don't forget to quote your variables.

Comment: Note this example will produce a different result that the examples in the question: The order does matter.

Comment: @richard Note, I do mention that in my paragraph.